# Pserve won't stop

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm pretty new to pyramid and pserve but I've run into a brick wall trying to stop pserve without just killing the processes.

I'm able to start pserve in production mode as follows:

```
/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/pserve /var/mypath/production.ini start --daemon --pid-file=/var/lock/watermark.pid --log-file=/var/www/5000.log --monitor-restart http_port=8080
```

But when I try to stop it as follows:

```
/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/pserve /var/mypath/production.ini stop --daemon --pid-file=/var/lock/watermark.pid --log-file=/var/www/5000.log --monitor-restart http_port=8080
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pserve", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pyramid==1.5a2', 'console_scripts', 'pserve')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyramid-1.5a2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 51, in main
    return command.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyramid-1.5a2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 229, in run
    result = self.stop_daemon()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyramid-1.5a2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 476, in stop_daemon
    kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)
OSError: [Errno 3] No such process
```

Any ideas why the stop command isn't working? It's on a linux ubuntu box if that makes a difference.

Comment: Are you sure your pid file really exists? Are you sure the process id inside it refers to the process id of your pyramid app?

Comment: The .pid file is written on startup. I have checked the pid file against the running processes and of the three pserve pids, it's one of the 2 parent processes.

Answer (score 0):

1) Get the number of process

```
ps -ef | grep pserve
testuser 26795     1  0 04:18 ?        00:00:00 /home/testuser/.virtualenvs/testapp/bin/python /home/testuser/.virtualenvs/testapp/bin/pserve production.ini start --daemon --pid-file=watermark.pid --log-file=5000.log --monitor-restart http_port=8080
```

2) Create pyramid.pid

```
touch pyramid.pid && echo "26795" >> pyramid.pid
```

3) Stop pserve :)

```
/home/testuser/.virtualenvs/testapp/bin/python /home/testuser/.virtualenvs/testapp/bin/pserve production.ini stop
```

Comment: This needs to be a startup script that executes automatically. See my comment above to @Antoine-Leclair where I point out that I have what appears to be the correct pid. Just looks like the pyramid shutdown command isn't stopping it.

Comment: You can not stop this process by pserve, because he will run again every time. For example you can kill it so:
   
     kill -9 \`ps -ef | grep "\-pid-file=./watermark.pid" | awk '{print $2}'\`

Comment: Interesting - let me give that a shot and get back to you